# Remove hyperlink on gallery shortcode

Tags: shortcode, gallery

I use a gallery shortcode in my index.php (theme directory) to display 3 boxes of images. The images are fetched from my Media.

```
<div class="well well-clear" style="padding-bottom: 0; margin-bottom: 0;">
<?php echo do_shortcode('[gallery ids="165,166,167"]'); ?>
</div>
```

By default these images have a hyperlink that when I click on it, a page will open and show the bigger version of this image. I don't want this to happen. Is there any option that I need to modify so that it will not hyperlink?

I'm new to WordPress, please don't be rough on me.

Comment: Shortcodes usually should be part of the content and not the code. The whole point is that the author can edit them.... If you know in advance what images you want to be displayed why not to hard code the exact HTML that you want to get?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Update:

It looks like there exists an attribute `link="none"` after all ;-)

For example:

```
[gallery link="none" ids="165,166,167"]
```

So we don't need to reinvent the wheel, like in my previous answers ;-)

### Previous: Plugin to handle `link="no"` in the gallery shortcode:

Here's a demo plugin to add the option to remove the image links in the gallery.

You can use the `link="no"` option to remove the links, for example:

```
[gallery link="no" ids="165,166,167"]
```

Create the folder `/wp-content/plugins/gallery-without-links/` and add the file `gallery-without-links.php` to it, containing the following code:

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: Gallery without links
 * Plugin URI: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/130349/26350
 * Description: Gallery with the link='no' option to remove links.
 */

/**
 * Init the WPSE_No_Gallery_Links class
 */
if( ! class_exists( 'WPSE_No_Gallery_Links' ) ):

    add_action( 'init', array( 'WPSE_No_Gallery_Links', 'get_instance' ) );

    class WPSE_No_Gallery_Links
    {
        static private $instance    = NULL;
        protected $nrofimgs         = 0;
        protected $counter      = 0;

        public function __construct()
        {
            add_filter( 'shortcode_atts_gallery', array( $this, 'shortcode_atts_gallery' ) );
        }

        static public function get_instance() 
        {        
            if ( NULL === self :: $instance )
               self :: $instance = new self;

            return self :: $instance;
        }


        public function wp_get_attachment_link( $link ){
            $this->counter++;
            if( $this->counter >= $this->nrofimgs )
            {
                $this->counter = 0;
                remove_action( 'wp_get_attachment_link', array( $this, 'wp_get_attachment_link' ) );
            }
            return strip_tags( $link, '<img>' );
        }

        public function shortcode_atts_gallery( $atts ) {
            if( 'no' === $atts['link'] )
            {
                if( isset( $atts['include'] ) )
                {
                    $this->nrofimgs = count( explode( ',', $atts['include'] ) );    
                    add_action( 'wp_get_attachment_link', array( $this, 'wp_get_attachment_link' ) );
                }
            }
            return $atts;
        }
    } // end of class

endif;
```

### Previous answer:

Here is one idea:

The gallery shortcode callback is using the `wp_get_attachment_link()` function to generate the link to each image in the gallery. We can therefore use the `wp_get_attachment_link` filter to strip out the `<a>` tags.

You could then modify your code snippet to:

```
<div class="well well-clear" style="padding-bottom: 0; margin-bottom: 0;">
    <?php     
       add_action( 'wp_get_attachment_link', 'custom_wp_get_attachment_link' );
       echo do_shortcode('[gallery ids="165,166,167"]'); 
       remove_action( 'wp_get_attachment_link', 'custom_wp_get_attachment_link' );
    ?>
</div>
```

where:

```
/**
 * Strip all tags except the <img> tag
 */
function custom_wp_get_attachment_link( $link )
{
    return strip_tags( $link, '<img>' );
}
```

Comment: On what file should I place this `function custom_wp_get_attachment_link()`?

Comment: You can try `functions.php` in your current theme directory.

Comment: Wow, works great. Isn't there an easy way? Like having an additional parameter in the gallery shortcode (eg. [gallery no-link="true"])?

Comment: I updated the answer, with a plugin to handle such a gallery shortcode attribute `link="no"`.

Comment: Check the updated answer, regarding the existing attribute: `link="none"` ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I just had a similar problem, and I used CSS targeted at the ul applying `pointer-events: none;`.
I'm using the gallery block and my current Wordpress version allows to introduce custom CSS directly on each block, so I did just that. No need to do CSS hunting.